# Getting ClassNotFoundException on Android device when running Eclipse mavenized app

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, classnotfoundexception

I've got mavenized Android app in Eclipse, which I do build & deploy by running these commands from command line:

```
mvn clean install
mvn android:deploy
```

From some moment, I am not able to run my Android app on the device, it crashes with message:

```
01-24 15:59:44.044: E/AndroidRuntime(25819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 15:59:44.044: E/AndroidRuntime(25819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.mycompany.myPackage.MyClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mycompany.myPackage.MyClass" on path: /data/app/com.mycompany.myPackage-1.apk
01-24 15:59:44.044: E/AndroidRuntime(25819):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
01-24 15:59:44.044: E/AndroidRuntime(25819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4529)
01-24 15:59:44.044: E/AndroidRuntime(25819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:150)
01-24 15:59:44.044: E/AndroidRuntime(25819):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
```

I've noticed that during running

```
mvn clean install
```

Eclipse pops out a error message:

Updating SVN status:
Could not remove \\target\classes\com\mycompany\myPackage\MyClass.class

If I close Eclipse and build application afterwards with

```
mvn clean install
```

then it's fine and app works on device.

Any ideas? Is this Eclipse problem or SVN?

Comment: as a first thing, I ran
svn resolve --accept working target/ and tried to commit everything inside of /target, but target doesn't exist in svn repository and I'm getting error: Operation failed because an added parent is not selected. Illegal target for the requested operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've managed to solve this issue by running this command on two folders.

```
svn resolve --accept working target/
svn resolve --accept working target/classes
```

Still not sure how did svn get to that situation...